# Do columns with the value NULL impact the performance of Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, datatable, null

I have a datatable with over 200 columns, however, in over half of those columns, the majority of my datarows has the value 'NULL'.

Do those NULL-values decrease the performance of my SQL Server or are fields with NULL-values irrelevant for all actions on the datatable?

Comment: With that many NULL values you might want to look into [sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Over 200 columns make me more worried.

Comment: It is for an ERP-System and this is one of the largest datatables of them all

Comment: Is there a specific area of performance you're concerned about?  Perhaps that would help improve the answers you're getting.  Your question is fairly broad at this point, and you'll find that if you narrow it down, the answer helpfulness increases

Answer (score 2):

Performance of the table is basically a function of I/O.  The way that SQL Server lays out rows on data pages means that NULL values might or might not take up space -- depending on the underlying data type.  SQL Server data pages contain a list of nullability bits for each column (even `NOT NULL` columns) to keep the `NULL` information.

Variable length strings simply use the `NULL` bits, so they occupy no additional space in each row.  Other data types do occupy space, even for `NULL` values (this includes fixed-length strings, I believe).

What impact does this have on performance?  If you have 200 NULL integer fields, that is 800 bytes on the data page.  That limits the number of records stored on a given page to no more than 10 records.  So, if you want to read 100 records, the query has to read (at least) 10 data pages.  If the table did not have these columns, then it might be able to read only one data page.

Whether or not this is important for a given query or set of queries depends on the queries.  But yes, columns that are `NULL` could have an impact on performance, particularly on the I/O side of queries.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from taking up space, and what little impact that may have on performance, they don't have any other effect.

Comment: So how do those NULL-values impact the SQL Server then?

Comment: They take up space.  I already said that, so I'm obviously not understanding your question.

Comment: as Sean in the 1st comment is tealling you use SPARSE columns bruh. It will help you. Also what is your end goal with removing nulls? Your building reports? ETL-ing all or specific non-null columns? Narrow down your request and you will get a lot clean/precise answer.